# Docusign add recipient with tabs after envelope is sent

Tags: docusignapi

I can create an envelope with recipients with tabs. I can also create an envelope, add additional recipients, then add tabs to those recipients. This takes two requests, (1) add recipient, (2) add tab to recipient. I can't get Docusign to add a recipient and tabs dynamically in one call. I've started by trying to get it to work using the REST API Explorer:

[PostEnvelopeRecipients](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=create)

[image]

Which results in the following request:

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "clientUserId": "1234",
      "email": "testuser6@example.com",
      "name": "tab testuser6",
      "recipientId": "1234",
      "tabs": {
        "signHereTabs": [
          {
            "documentId": "1",
            "pageNumber": "1",
            "xPosition": "200",
            "yPosition": "200"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This results in a recipient being added to the envelope properly, however it does not have any tabs. How can I add tabs when creating a recipient after the envelope is already created in one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to add Tabs using the [PostEnvelopeRecipients](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=create) or [PutEnvelopeRecipients](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeRecipients&operations=update) api. After an envelope is created/sent, two separate calls are required to add recipients and tabs.